# Efficient way to write huge boost dynamic_bitset vector to a file and read it back

Tags: c++, boost, file-io, boost-dynamic-bitset

I have a huge vector of [boost dynamic_bitset](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_36_0/libs/dynamic_bitset/dynamic_bitset.html). I want to write the dynamic_bitset vector to a file and later read the file back into a dynamic_bitset vector. Is the memory for dynamic_bitset allocated as a contiguous block of memory (so that I can write the entire vector at once without traversing) ?

The size of the bitset vector is in order of millions. So I am looking for an efficient way to write them to a file instead of iterating through the elements.

I converted the dynamic_bitset to a string and then wrote the string to a file. Later read the string from the file and converted it back to dynamic_bitset.

Below is the code I wrote in C++ using Visual Studio:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <boost/dynamic_bitset.hpp>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  // Initializing a bitset vector to 0s
  boost::dynamic_bitset<> bit_vector(10); 
  bit_vector[0] = 1;   bit_vector[1] = 1;  bit_vector[4] = 1;  bit_vector[7] = 1;  bit_vector[9] = 1;
  cout<<"Input :"<<bit_vector<<endl; //Prints in reverse order

  //Converting dynamic_bitset to a string
  string buffer;
  to_string(bit_vector, buffer);

  //Writing the string to a file
  ofstream out("file", ios::out | ios::binary);  
  char *c_buffer = (char*)buffer.c_str();   
  out.write(c_buffer, strlen(c_buffer));
  out.close();

  //Find length of the string and reading from the file
  int len = strlen(c_buffer);
  char* c_bit_vector = new char(len+1);
  ifstream in;
  in.open("file", ios::binary);
  in.read(c_bit_vector, len);
  c_bit_vector[len] = 0;
  in.close();

  //Converting string back to dynamic_bitset
  string str2 = c_bit_vector;
  boost::dynamic_bitset<> output_bit_vector( str2 );
  cout<<"Output:"<<output_bit_vector<<endl;

  system("PAUSE");
  return 0;
}
```

But even this method, storing it as a string, takes a long time to write to the file. And when I try to read back from the file into the string, I get an "unhandled access violation exception". Is there a more efficient way to implement the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hm... mb use operator << and operator >>?

```
template <typename Ch, typename Tr, typename Block, typename Alloc>
std::basic_ostream<Ch, Tr>&
operator<<(std::basic_ostream<Ch, Tr>& os,
           const dynamic_bitset<Block, Alloc>& b)

template <typename Ch, typename Tr, typename Block, typename Alloc>
std::basic_istream<Ch, Tr>&
operator>>(std::basic_istream<Ch, Tr>& is, dynamic_bitset<Block, Alloc>& b)
```